# Как выбрать записи, у которых нет соотв. записей в связанной таблице, а также записи, которые соответствуют условиям?

Tags: mysql

Таблица `users`:

| id | surname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Иванов |
| 2 | Петров |
| 3 | Сидоров |
| 4 | Кузнецов |

Таблица `category`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Котики |
| 2 | Собачки |

Таблица `posts`

| id | id_user | content | id_category | add_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Текст 1 | 1 | 2023.01.01 |
| 2 | 1 | Текст 2 | 1 | 2023.01.02 |
| 3 | 1 | Текст 3 | 2 | 2023.01.03 |
| 4 | 2 | Текст 4 | 1 | 2023.01.04 |
| 5 | 1 | Текст 5 | 2 | 2023.01.05 |
| 6 | 2 | Текст 6 | 2 | 2023.01.06 |
| 7 | 2 | Текст 7 | 1 | 2023.01.07 |

Нужно получить `users.surname`, `category.name`, `posts.content` где: (`posts.id_category = 1`) И (`posts.add_date < '2023.01.03'` ИЛИ `posts.add_date > '2023.01.05'` ИЛИ вообще нет записей в `posts`). То есть в итоге я хочу получить такое:

| users.surname | category.name | posts.content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Иванов | Котики | Текст 1 |
| Иванов | Котики | Текст 2 |
| Петров | Котики | Текст 7 |
| Сидоров | Котики | NULL |
| Кузнецов | Котики | NULL |

Реально сделать такой запрос? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Чтобы таблицы отображались правильно перед ними должна быть одна пустая строка.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто прочитал вопрос. Я уже нашел решение с помощью подзапроса SELECT в WHERE. Кого вдруг будет интересовать подобное - копайте в сторону:

```
... LEFT JOIN posts ... WHERE ... OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT posts.id FROM posts WHERE posts.id_category = 1 AND users.id = posts.id_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто перенесите условия фильтра в секцию ON у LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT users.surname, category.name, posts.content
FROM users
CROSS JOIN category
LEFT JOIN posts ON (users.id = posts.id_user AND category.id = posts.id_category
 AND posts.id_category = 1 AND (posts.add_date < '2023.01.03' OR posts.add_date > '2023.01.05')
```